# Linear mixed effects model with permutation testing

Tags: r, permutation, mixed-models

I need to compare two groups of participants to each other in a model that contains fixed and random effects in R. It was suggested to me that a non-parametric test might be ideal for these comparisons. Here is the data:

```r
structure(list(item = c("'accordion_1'", "'accordion_3'", "'apple_01'", 
"'apple_03'", "'asian_01'", "'asian_02'"), avg = c(3.177631579, 
2.868421053, 4.421052632, 4.526315789, 4.440789474, 4.0625), 
    subcat = c("c", "c", "g", "g", "h", "h"), cat = c(1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), group_num = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), group_name = c("adu", 
    "adu", "adu", "adu", "adu", "adu")), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I have scoured the internet for code to accomplish this (I am new to both these methods). I initially started by using `perm.lmer()` in the `permutes` package with this code:

```r
asd_kid_mod <- perm.lmer(avg ~ group_name * cat + (1|item), 
    data = asd_kid, nperm = 1000, type = "anova")
```

but it returned p values at 0 which seems strange to me. I also am not sure if mean permutation testing would simply be more appropriate for my data. So I guess my questions are:

1.) What is the best method for permutation testing for LMMs in R?
2.) Would it make more sense to use mean permutation testing?

EDIT:
Here is my output form `summary`:

```
         Factor df       LRT          F  p
1    (Intercept)  1 555.54630 253.445582 NA
2     group_name  1  29.48206   1.643257  0
3            cat  1 220.76503  24.153896  0
4 group_name:cat  1  64.43601   4.027463  0
```

and here's a link to what I mean by mean permutation testing: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-permutation-tests-bacc79f45749

I believe it would be using means instead of medians based on the link above

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! (1) It would be good to have a [mcve] (this isn't your *full* data set, right ... ??).  At the very least, please edit your question to include the output of `summary()` (cut-and-pasted in a code block, not as a screenshot ...) (2) can you explain/link what you mean by "mean permutation testing" ?

Comment: If you are seeking method recommendations, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. R is just a calculator. Choosing which methods to use on your data is a statistical question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

It's  hard to know for sure without looking at the details of your model to see if everything makes sense, but: when you use a permutation-based test, any term for which the permutation-based p-value is considerably less than `1/nsims` will be reported as 0, because the p-value is essentially being computed as "proportion *of simulated trials/permutations* for which the test statistic was >= that observed from the real data"; if the real p-value is less than 0.001 (for example), it's likely that none of the 1000 simulations you ran will satisfy the condition.  For example:

```r
library(lmerTest)
library(permutes)
set.seed(101)
p1 <- perm.lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject),
    data = sleepstudy, nperm = 1000, type = "anova")
```

```
       Factor df      LRT          F  p
1 (Intercept)  1 855.7315 1357.04485 NA
2        Days  1 341.9547   45.85296  0
```

You can compare with the standard parametric approach:

```r
p2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), data = sleepstudy)
printCoefmat(coef(summary(p2)))
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 251.4051     6.8246  16.9997 36.8381 < 2.2e-16 ***
Days         10.4673     1.5458  17.0000  6.7715 3.264e-06 ***
```

In general, the p-value for the permutation model are usually *somewhere* in the ballpark of the parametric p-values (but more reliable).

If you have the time and compute power, you could run 100 or 1000x more simulations and see if any of your p-values seem to in a lower range (but if the evidence is strong, it's not unusual to have p-values that are extremely small, requiring millions of simulations if you want to be able to detect a non-zero value ...)

Comment: I believe it is common to calculate the p-value as (n_{>=} + 1)/n, which ensures that you never get a zero p-value.

Comment: I agree, and almost mentioned that, but since it doesn't seem to be the way that the package is doing it ...